# Add hashed password to txt file

Tags: php, html

Hello I know this is not safe but it's just for testing purposes.
I want to get the password from my form, hash it, and put the hashed password in a text file, along with the username and email

```
<?php
   $plaintext_password = "$_POST['Password']"; 

  $hash = "password_hash($plaintext_password,  
          PASSWORD_DEFAULT)"; 


$numberNewline = $_POST['Name'] .|. $_POST['Email'].|. $hash . "\n";

file_put_contents('accounts.txt', $numberNewline ,FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of unnecessary double quotes. Function calls are not expanded inside quotes. And if you put an array access inside quotes, you either have to remove the `'` around the index or put the indexed variable inside `{}`. But there's no need to put quotes around a variable that's all by itself.

```
<?php
$plaintext_password = $_POST['Password']; 
$hash = password_hash($plaintext_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
$numberNewline = $_POST['Name'] .|. $_POST['Email'].|. $hash . "\n";
file_put_contents('accounts.txt', $numberNewline ,FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: this doesn't create a accounts.txt file though, thats the main issue.

Comment: That's what `file_put_contents()` does, why don't you think it will do that?

Comment: Is it getting an error? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning to see warning messages.

Comment: I know, but whenever I try to run the script, it doesn't create the file. I don't know why

Comment: Does the webserver userid have permission to create the file?

Comment: Try using `/tmp/accounts.txt` instead, it should have permission for that.

Comment: No that still doesn't work. But the thing is, if I take out the hashing process and just do

```
<?php



$numberNewline = $_POST['Name'] .|. $_POST['Email'] .|. $_POST['Password'] ."\n";

file_put_contents('accounts.txt', $numberNewline ,FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

then that does work

Comment: and I don't know why

Comment: did you enable error reporting and review the log to see if you're getting an error?